# JPA entity relationship dependent on other field

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

My database has a table that represents the common fields between a bunch of other things. So lets say there's one table like `Vehicle` and then `Vehicle` has fields like VIN, color, type...

Then there are other tables like `Car` and `Truck` and when the "type" on the `Vehicle` is "car" we want to look at the `Car` table to find other properties. Maybe stuff about fuelEfficiency and numPassengers. When type is "truck" we want to know things about trucks like maybe loadCapacity or whatever.

How do you model something like this? Do you Embed the `Vehicle` into all of the other types? Is there a way to do like a `@OneToOne` between the tables conditionally on the "type" field?

Comment: Depends on how you are designing your schema and how you are going to access it... so is modifying schema an option? Or is there a REST layer on top of this?

Comment: I guess I could modify the schema... but it exists. And I am writing REST on top of it.

Comment: Why don't you go for `HAS-A` relationship (Aggregation )!!! But you may modify some codes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MappedSuperClass or a JoinedTable strategy, if you want to follow the real ORM way of doing this. But it comes with a cost. There are other overheads, such as querying restrictions and more joins per query etc that comes with these strategies.

If you denormalize the tables, you could use a datafilter strategy (only hibernate supports I think). But now you have everything in a single class and that could be a bigger problem to deal with.

Since you are using REST, you are probably looking to cater /api/vehicles/1 (correct me pls)

For such scenarios, it is easier to perform this using a "Vehicle" table which contains the "type" in it. You can use a jackson serializer to omit all non-null components. So in the case of a car, vehicle attributes and car parameters will come in, but null values on truck, bus etc will be omitted.